# Can't use dynamic variable into JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable TableSorter plugin on some th.
These th have class="disableSorter", so I do:

```
$('.disableSorter').each(function(index) {

    $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({ headers: { index: { sorter: false} } }); 

});
```

where index: is the index variable passed in the function.
The thing is " index " is not replaced by the number (for example 0:, 1: 5:, etc.)

Thanks for help!

**===== Edit =====**

Thanks JaredPar, your solution was right about the dynamic variable. I had to edit the code because I wan't getting the index of the th element, but the index of the each loop.

Here's my final code

```
var inner = {};
$('.disableSorter').each(function() {
    inner[$('.tablesorter th').index(this)] = { sorter: false };
});

$('.tablesorter').tablesorter({ headers: inner  });
```

Comment: I suggest you modify the title to "Can't use dynamic variable in place of object index in JQuery Plugin call"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you're trying to use the value in a place where javascript is not looking for values but instead for literals to use as names.  You need to use the `[]` syntax to create a named member based on a value.

Try the following

```
$('.disableSorter').each(function(index) {
  var inner = {};
  inner[index] = { sorter: false };
  $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({ headers: inner); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var obj = null;
$('.disableSorter').each(function(index) {
    obj = {};
    obj.headers = {};
    obj.headers[index] = { sorter: false };
    $('.tablesorter').tablesorter(obj); 

});
```